# WatchKit + Swift 3.1: Cannot override 'handleAction' which has been marked unavailable

Tags: swift3, xcode8, watchkit

Prior to Swift 3.1, the following code did compile and work without any issues:

```
import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    override func handleAction(withIdentifier identifier: String?, for notification: UNNotification) {

    // Do something

    }
}
```

However, when compiling in Xcode 8.3 with Swift 3.1 and WatchKit version 3.0, I get the following compiler error:

> Cannot override 'handleAction' which has been marked unavailable

Removing `override` from the code gives another compiler error:

> Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1648286-handleaction), method `handleAction` with `UNNotification` is still a valid non-deprecated method of WKInterfaceController, so the code above should be valid and compilable. Setting the WatchKit version to 3.1 or 3.2 does not change anything.

Any ideas to get this working with Swift 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

With thanks to Nycen, who pushed me to look again at the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, I ended up with implementing the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in the ExtensionDelegate of my WatchKit project, to handle UNNotifications in the root controller, like this:

```
import WatchKit
import UserNotifications

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let controller = WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController as? InterfaceController {
            // Call to a custom method in the root interface controller to handle the notification
            controller.handleAction(notification: response.notification)
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not much love for my answer though. Maybe upvote and/or accept it ;)

Comment: @Nycen I don't see hard proof anywhere for your statement that 'handleAction' with UNNotification has been deprecated. Except for the fact that it gives a compiler error, but this can be a bug at Apple's side. To go further I just implemented the delegate.

Comment: Your question was "Any ideas to get this working with Swift 3.1?". You got it working thanks to the first line of my answer, "UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate". That's not very fair.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: you need to use "UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate"**

You are 2 steps behind, and Apple's API Reference currently is one step behind.

The current online API Reference [mentions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619530-handleaction?changes=latest_major):

> Deprecated
>
> Use handle​Action(with​Identifier:​for:​) instead.

But this has been deprecated too, and if you open the WKInterfaceController class definition, you will find the following (line 238):

```
// deprecated
@available(watchOS 2.0, *)
@available(watchOS, deprecated: 3.0, message: "use UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate")
open func handleAction(withIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification remoteNotification: [AnyHashable : Any])

@available(watchOS 2.0, *)
@available(watchOS, deprecated: 3.0, message: "use UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate")
open func handleAction(withIdentifier identifier: String?, for localNotification: UILocalNotification)
```

As you can see, this is deprecated too, but it points in the right direction: "use UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate".
To put it differently, you could think from the API reference that you are using a method that is not deprecated, but it is.

This is related to the XCode update, I don't think it has anything to do with Swift 3.1.

Comment: These two deprecated methods are the old ones, the last one based on UILocalNotification. They do not match the method in my question.

Comment: With other words: these two deprecation warnings don't prove that the advised new method (based on UNNotification, not UILocalNotification) is deprecated as well.

Comment: The last two methods are even more deprecated then the first method quoted (which matches your signature), and have nothing to do with the answer: use UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Comment: I added a line at the end to clarify this.